# Basic JavaScript: random positioning

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a square that will appear in a random place within a 300x300px space.  It is currently moving horizontally but not vertically.  Can someone help me get it to move vertically as well?  Thank you!

```
        #square {width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        }

        var top=Math.random();
                top=top*300;                
        var left=Math.random();
                left=left*300;                      
        document.getElementById("square").style.top=top+"px";                   
        document.getElementById("square").style.left=left+"px";
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/f3chy9mk/ The problem is somewhere else. You'll have to show an example that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left` to translate horizontally and `top` for vertically.

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

const square= document.querySelector('#square');
setInterval(() => {
   square.style.left= getRandom(0, 300 - 200)+'px'; //  Horizontally
   square.style.top = getRandom(0, 300 - 200)+'px'; //  Vertically
    
}, 500); // every 1/2 second
```

```css
#space {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #eee
}
#square {

 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #8e4435
}
```

```html
<div id="space">
  <div id="square">

   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `display: none` it should be good, compare with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3cmro0ph/).

Also you could simplify with this:

```
 var top = Math.random() * 300;
```